# Web App for Office365 and Google Marketplace

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, office365, google-apps-marketplace

I want to build a single web app that is available as an Office 365 App and a Google App in the marketplace. I am using ASP.Net MVC and have looked at the following samples and got them working separately. I can't figure out how to merge them into a single app.

Is this even possible?

https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-WebApp-MultiTenant

http://www.oauthforaspnet.com/providers/google/guides/aspnet-mvc5/

Comment: Did you mean that you want the web app enable users login in with office 365 account or google account?

Comment: I would like to create a single web app (ASP.Net MVC) that can be used by an Office 365 user and a Google Apps Marketplace user. In essence, someone using Office 365 can enable my app and O365 users would then invoke my app via their O365 app launcher and similar for a Google apps user. Hope this clarifies- tx!